# How to reduce the number of links in Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

How to reduce the number of visible buttons during pagination in Laravel. I have tried many methods but none of them work correctly

The `$onEachSide=1` method does not work as it should

This is what the pagination looks like now

[image]

And that's what I need

[image]

Here is the pagination code

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#adjusting-the-pagination-link-window mentions on how to adjust the number of links.

Comment: I wrote in the question that this method does not work well, in the first photo $onEachSide=1

Comment: That's a variable, but you don't say where you put it. My link mentions a method to be used when you use the `links()` function. Is the pagination code you're showing the default Laravel pagination blade, or one you've created yourself?

Comment: default Laravel pagination blade
{{ $items->onEachSide(1)->appends(\Request::except('page'))->links('parts.pagination-view') }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I achieved what I wanted.
It is not perfect, but it will cope with its task perfectly

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
{{--    Custom default component--}}
    <nav role="navigation" aria-label="{{ __('Pagination Navigation') }}" class="flex items-center justify-center">
        <span class="relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <span aria-disabled="true" aria-label="{{ __('pagination.previous') }}">
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center px-1 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default rounded-l-md leading-5" aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </span>
            @else
                <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-1 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-l-md leading-5 hover:text-gray-400 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-500 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="{{ __('pagination.previous') }}">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @if($paginator->currentPage() > 2)
                <a href="{{ $paginator->url(1) }}" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-success bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 hover:text-black hover:bg-gray-100 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="{{ __('Go to page :page', ['page' => 1]) }}">
                    1
                </a>
            @endif
            @if($paginator->currentPage() > 3)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                <span aria-disabled="true">
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center p-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5">...</span>
                </span>
            @endif
            @foreach(range(1, $paginator->lastPage()) as $i)
                @if($i >= $paginator->currentPage() - 1 && $i <= $paginator->currentPage() + 1)
                    @if ($i == $paginator->currentPage())
                        <span aria-current="page">
                            <span class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium badge-success border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5">{{ $i }}</span>
                        </span>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ $paginator->url($i) }}" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-success bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 hover:text-black hover:bg-gray-100 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="{{ __('Go to page :page', ['page' => $i]) }}">
                            {{ $i }}
                        </a>
                    @endif
                @endif
            @endforeach
            @if($paginator->currentPage() < $paginator->lastPage() - 2)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                <span aria-disabled="true">
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center p-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default leading-5">...</span>
                </span>
            @endif
            @if($paginator->currentPage() < $paginator->lastPage() - 1)
                <a href="{{ $paginator->url($paginator->lastPage()) }}" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-success bg-white border border-gray-300 leading-5 hover:text-black hover:bg-gray-100 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-700 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="{{ __('Go to page :page', ['page' => $paginator->lastPage()]) }}">
                    {{ $paginator->lastPage() }}
                </a>
            @endif

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-1 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-r-md leading-5 hover:text-gray-400 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring ring-gray-300 focus:border-blue-300 active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-500 transition ease-in-out duration-150" aria-label="{{ __('pagination.next') }}">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            @else
                <span aria-disabled="true" aria-label="{{ __('pagination.next') }}">
                    <span class="relative inline-flex items-center px-1 py-2 -ml-px text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 cursor-default rounded-r-md leading-5" aria-hidden="true">
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </span>
            @endif
        </span>
    </nav>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pagination function I wrote from scratch to achieve this compact mode. You may adapt the logic into your template format. I provide it as-is hope it helps.

```
public static function draw_pagination_as_html_compact($total, $page, $page_size, $prefix = "crud/list/table-name/", $suffix = "/&q=that", $before_non_one = "")
{
    if ($total <= $page_size) {
        return "";

    }

    $pages = ceil($total / $page_size);
    $output = [];

    $page = min($pages, $page);
    $page = max(1, $page);

    // previous
    if ($page > 1) {
        $output[] = '<li><a href="?path=' . ($prefix) . (intval($page - 1) > 1 ? ($before_non_one . intval($page - 1) . '') : '') . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">«</a></li>';
    } else {
        $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>«</a></li>';
    }

    // page links
    $did_first_ellipsis = false;
    $did_last_ellipsis = false;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        $active = ($i == $page) ? ' class="active"' : "";

        if ($pages <= 7) {

            // normal
            $output[] = '<li' . $active . '><a href="?path=' . ($prefix) . (intval($i) > 1 ? ($before_non_one . intval($i)) . '' : '') . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">' . $i . '</a></li>';
        } else {
            if ($page <= 4) {

                // start
                if ($i <= 5 || $i == $pages) {
                    $output[] = '<li' . $active . '><a href="?path=' . ($prefix) . (intval($i) > 1 ? ($before_non_one . intval($i)) . '' : '') . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                } else {
                    if (!$did_first_ellipsis) {
                        $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>';
                    }
                    $did_first_ellipsis = true;
                }
            } else if ($page >= $pages - 3) {

                // end
                if ($i == 1 || $i >= $pages - 4) {
                    $output[] = '<li' . $active . '><a href="?path=' . ($prefix) . (intval($i) > 1 ? ($before_non_one . intval($i)) . '' : '') . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                } else {
                    if (!$did_last_ellipsis) {
                        $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>';
                    }
                    $did_last_ellipsis = true;
                }
            } else {

                // middle
                if ($i == 1 || $i == $pages || abs($i - $page) <= 1) {
                    $output[] = '<li' . $active . '><a href="?path=' . ($prefix) . (intval($i) > 1 ? ($before_non_one . intval($i)) . '' : '') . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                } else {
                    if ($i < $page) {
                        if (!$did_first_ellipsis) {
                            $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>';
                        }
                        $did_first_ellipsis = true;
                    } else {
                        if (!$did_last_ellipsis) {
                            $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>';
                        }
                        $did_last_ellipsis = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }

    // next
    if ($page < $pages) {
        $output[] = '<li><a href="?path=' . ($prefix . $before_non_one) . (intval($page) + 1) . ($suffix) . '" data-hijack="click">»</a></li>';
    } else {
        $output[] = '<li class="disabled"><a>»</a></li>';
    }

    $pages = implode("\n\t", $output);

    $html = Project::get_template("tables/table-pagination.html", [
        '$pages' => $pages,
    ]);
    return $html;
}
```

Here are some HTML outputs

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="pagination-container">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/3" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/2" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/3" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">3</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="?path=entries/proxies/4" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/5" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">5</a></li>
    <li><a class="disabled">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/9" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/5" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="pagination-container">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/4" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="disabled">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/4" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">4</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="?path=entries/proxies/5" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/6" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">6</a></li>
    <li><a class="disabled">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/9" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/6" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pagination-container">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/5" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="disabled">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/5" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">5</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="?path=entries/proxies/6" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/7" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/8" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/9" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">9</a></li>
    <li><a href="?path=entries/proxies/7" data-hijack="click" class="already-hijacked">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not tried your method, but it seems to me that it is not the best practice. Generate html on the backend. Each project has different pagination